# How to fix Blender 3.0 animation flicker?

Tags: animation

I'm new to Blender 3.0 animations and one of my test animations (a martian sunrise) has some unwanted brightness flicker, especially noticeable on the foreground landscape:

https://youtu.be/rPX2yrO9DJI

Any idea what's causing this? And how to fix it?

The sun and atmosphere is created by an addon called, "Physical Starlight and Atmosphere;" this is the first time I've seen it flicker.

**Output settings:**

bpy.context.scene.render.use_file_extension = True
bpy.context.scene.render.use_render_cache = False
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_mode = 'RGB'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.views_format = 'INDIVIDUAL'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.compression = 15
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.quality = 90
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.jpeg2k_codec = 'JP2'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.use_jpeg2k_cinema_preset = False
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.use_jpeg2k_cinema_48 = False
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.use_jpeg2k_ycc = False
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.use_cineon_log = False
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_depth = '8'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.exr_codec = 'ZIP'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.use_zbuffer = False
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.use_preview = False
bpy.context.scene.render.use_overwrite = True
bpy.context.scene.render.use_placeholder = False
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.tiff_codec = 'DEFLATE'

**Blender 3.0, Windows 11**

Comment: Sorry ... I don't see any flickering in provided video.

Comment: No flickering here under Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Uploading the video to YouTube appears to have diminished the flickering, but it's still present.